# RecyclerView not refreshing onClick

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, refresh

The `RecyclerView` is getting refreshed fine when I call for it in the main activity, but when I use a `FloatingActionButton` it no longer works, and it is not giving any errors as to why.

The `onCreate` method from the `MainActivity`

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    //Initially get the events
    dh.getEvents();

    //Initially setting the list fragment
    EventListFragment eventListFragment = new EventListFragment();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame, eventListFragment, "list_fragment");
    fragmentTransaction.commit();

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            dh.getEvents();
        }
    });
}
```

This is the `getEvents()` method from the `DataHandaling` class

```
public void getEvents() {

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(enviroClass.url() + "/api/events/" + 7)
            .build();

    client.newCall(request)
            .enqueue(new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                    try {
                        JSONObject eventObject = new JSONObject(response.body().string());
                        JSONArray eventJsonArray = eventObject.getJSONArray("events");
                        for (int i = 0; i<eventJsonArray.length(); i++) {
                            eventObject = eventJsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            eventObject = eventObject.getJSONObject("event");
                            eventArray.add(new Event(eventObject.getString("name"), eventObject.getString("address"), eventObject.getString("image"), "100", eventObject.getString("description"), eventObject.getString("start_date"), eventObject.getString("end_date"), eventObject.getInt("id")));
                        }
                        EventListAdapter adapter = new EventListAdapter(eventArray, null);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

**UPDATE**

This is the RecyclerAdapter that is being used

```
public class EventListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<EventListAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    DataHandaling dh = new DataHandaling();

    private static ArrayList<Event> mValues;
    private OnListFragmentInteractionListener mListener = null;

    public EventListAdapter(ArrayList<Event> items, OnListFragmentInteractionListener listener) {
        if (items != null) {
            mValues = items;
        }
        if (listener != null ) {
            mListener = listener;
        }
    }

    public void swap(ArrayList<Event> eventArray) {
        mValues.clear();

        mValues.addAll(eventArray);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.fragment_item, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.mItem = mValues.get(position);
        holder.mIdView.setText(mValues.get(position).getStarTime());
        holder.mContentView.setText(mValues.get(position).getName());
        Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(mValues.get(position).getImage()).into(holder.mImageView);

        holder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (null != mListener) {
                    // Notify the active callbacks interface (the activity, if the
                    // fragment is attached to one) that an item has been selected.
                    mListener.onListFragmentInteraction(position);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mValues.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public final View mView;
        public final TextView mIdView;
        public final TextView mContentView;
        public final ImageView mImageView;
        public Event mItem;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            mView = view;
            mIdView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.id);
            mContentView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.content);
            mImageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.eventImage);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return super.toString() + " '" + mContentView.getText() + "'";
        }
    }
}
```

This is the Fragment onCreateView, where the adapter is set

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_item_list, container, false);

    // Set the adapter
    if (view instanceof RecyclerView) {
        Context context = view.getContext();
        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view;
        if (mColumnCount <= 1) {
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
        } else {
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(context, mColumnCount));
        }

        recyclerView.setAdapter(new EventListAdapter(dh.getEventArray(), mListener));
    }
    return view;
}
```

Comment: you sure that you are getting the new data here `.url(enviroClass.url() + "/api/events/" + 7)` ?

Comment: @Ibrahim Ali, Yup because it's working when I first start the app and I double checked it with postman... just in case XD, It's only when I try use the button to refresh that it doesn't work

Comment: Could you post EventListAdapter please ?

Comment: then please `log` on the `eventArray` and `adapter` if cached data as well.

Comment: Please check my answer. Where did you call myRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter) ?

Comment: @Ibrahim Ali, I'm not entirely sure what you're asking me to do, The eventArray is populated though if that helps xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create a new adapter, you need to set it in the `RecyclerView`

```
 EventListAdapter adapter = new EventListAdapter(eventArray, null);
 myRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter)
```

The class `DataHandling` should have access to `RecyclerView`

Or you could use the previous created adapter :

In fragment, change :

```
recyclerView.setAdapter(new EventListAdapter(dh.getEventArray(), mListener));
```

by

```
mAdapter = new EventListAdapter(dh.getEventArray(), mListener)
recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

In getEvents() :

```
mAdapter.swap(eventArray);
```

It means that `DataHandling` class should have access to `mAdapter`, you could pass it in contructor, or you should move `getEvents()` to Fragment and delete `DataHandling` class

Comment: I used a similar method earlier that also worked when the app first started but then didn't work when I wanted to refresh afterwards


       `public void swap(ArrayList<Event> eventArray) {
        mValues.clear();

        mValues.addAll(eventArray);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }`

Comment: I don't see in your code where do you call myRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter)

Comment: Ok I have edited the question to show you the onCreateView for the ListFragment, This is where the adapter is first set, and the reason it hasn't been set in the question or in the method that I showed you is because I don't know how to set it like that outside the fragment xD

Comment: Ok, So it took me a while to get it working how you suggested, BUT... now it is refreshing... So the getEvents() is now in the fragment itself... My problem is that now I need to get the eventArray from within the fragment to pass to a new activity when the user selects an Item on the list???

Comment: i would suggest you to post a new question for this or check to previously asked answers